# undefined: syscall.SIGURG on a working code

Tags: go, system-calls

I am new to go currently trying to understand some code wrote by a coworker

```golang
go func() {
    s := <-sigs
    if s == syscall.SIGURG {
        fmt.Println("received sigur")
    } else {
        log.Printf("RECEIVED SIGNAL: %s", s)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}()
```

I used both GoLand & VSCode and those two IDE report an error on `if s == syscall.SIGURG {`
They throw `undefined: syscall.SIGURG`

The thing is, I know this code works on Debian. So I'm trying why it's not working on my Windows computer

I have the required imports though :

```golang
import ( 
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)
```

Comment: Windows has no SIGURG.

Comment: Is it impossible to simulate it ? Otherwise I'll dual boot on Debian from now on.

Could you write it as an answer and not a command, so I'll accept it ?

Comment: You don't need to dual boot, if your primary OS is Windows, you can use WSL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about

Comment: No, you cannot "simulate" a nonexisting  signal. What you can do: guard that piece of code  in a xyz_linux.go file and have a seperate xyz_windows.go which provided the same API (but doesn't use SIGURG). Or just stop using Windows :-)

Comment: I'll use WSL till I can code on Debian yep !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Volker wrote in a comment, `SIGURG` does not exist on Windows. It exists on Unix-like systems, like Debian.

I believe if you change the code to use `golang.org/x/sys/unix` instead of `syscall`, the behavior would be much more obvious to you. The Golang documentation for the `syscall` package has [the following deprecation notice](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/):

> Deprecated: this package is locked down. Callers should use the corresponding package in the [golang.org/x/sys](https://pkg.go.dev/mod/golang.org/x/sys) repository instead. That is also where updates required by new systems or versions should be applied. See https://golang.org/s/go1.4-syscall for more information.

There is also the package [`golang.org/x/sys/windows`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20200812155832-6a926be9bd1d/windows) for Windows, and it does not include `SIGURG`, because it does not exist on Windows.

Comment: That's the correct answer. I just want to add that I'll use WSL as mentionned by @marco.m till I can code on Debian like I should.